# Why is my hover overlay not working after a website hack?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hover, overlay, malware

I'm in the process of repairing a Wordpress website hack, and *almost* everything is back to normal. I have sought professional help to clean it, replace files, and delete the malware, and it's looking good. 
BUT for some reason my Hover Overlay effect isn't working now.

I've checked my footer.php and .css, and both should be normal. Any advice?

**Here's the CSS:**

```
  #image .image:hover .overlay  {

}

 .overlay {
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 20px;
 left: 20px;
 height: calc(100% - 40px) ;
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
 opacity: 1;
 transition: 1s ease;
 background-color: #008CBA;


}

.overlay-inner{
  position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 49%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;

}
```

**Here's the JS, found in my footer.php:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(window).load(function() {
  var container = 
document.querySelector('#imagewrapper');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.image',
    columnWidth: '.image',
  });
$('.overlay').css('visibility', 'visible')
});

var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'pink', 'gray', 
'#F9CD19', '#198CF9', '#C59FF9', '#F86A4A'];

jQuery('.overlay').each(function(index, item) {
  var index = Math.round(Math.random() * 
colors.length - 1);
  jQuery(this).css('background-color', 
colors[index]);
    })


    jQuery('.image').on('mouseover',function(){
      jQuery(this).find('.overlay').show();
    });
    jQuery('.image').on('mouseout',function(){
      jQuery(this).find('.overlay').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas or advice you could share?

Comment: Can you also add an example of your html structure?

Comment: Sure! I'm a little new to the coding world. In which file/area would this be found?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to right click on the page which contains the element --> Show source code --> search for `imagewrapper` and copy the html content inside this tag

Comment: You may do the following for troubleshooting purpose: 1>make sure the js script is loaded to the front end; 2> add "console.log("mouseover called");" and "console.log("mouseout called");" to see if the event is trigger; 3> use browser developer tool to check the inline css of .overlay. If show() is called, it should be like this<div class="overlay" style="display: block">;

Comment: do you mean by "your Hover Overlay" this part of code `#image .image:hover .overlay` in the CSS

Comment: Yes, exactly. That part. @evgenifotia

Comment: can you post the html code do a right click on the page which contains the element --> Show source code --> search-->Ctrl+F then writ  "#image"